# Keep tcp connection open with native JDBS driver

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, tcp

I am querying mysql and postgres and I want to be able to keep the tcp connection open with my JDBS driver so that the queries may execute faster, without having to open the tcp connection each time a query is run.

Is this possible to do with a param, if not, where would the inner driver be modified to do this?

Comment: You mean you're looking for a connection pool?

Comment: @Kayaman yes, basically.

Comment: Do you mean *JDBC?* If you're looking for a JDBC connection pool, see the Apache DBCP project. Off topic.

Comment: Why not HikariCP? :)

Comment: @Kayaman cool, that's what we ended up using!